Use complex type inference in Key Remapping
Here is a piece of code that confuses me:
type Foo<T extends string> = [T] extends [infer Y] ? Y : never

// ok
type Test_2<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [P in T[number] as Foo<"foo">]: undefined
}

// ok
type Test_3<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [P in T[number] as Foo<string>]: undefined
}

// error!!!
type Test<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [P in T[number] as Foo<P>]: undefined
//                   ^^^^^^
// Type 'Foo<P>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
//   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
}

P is a generic type parameter constrained to string, it should compile successfully,
but it actually shows me an error. I don't know where the unknown comes from.

TS doesn't use constraint information when inferring, as reported in ms/TS#23132 and essentially ms/TS#45281. So Last doesn't "know" that Y is a string, even though it probably should. You can use an extends clause as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what am I missing?

Based on your links, I created a reproduction code that produces the same error. Does this mean that Foo will not use constraint information only when using dynamic generic parameters, where P comes from T[number] and T is not yet specified? In my view, P is a dynamic generic parameter with constraints.

There's no "constraint information" to use for Foo<"foo"> or Foo<string>. Those are eagerly evaluated as "foo" and string, which are specific types.  But yes, P, a generic type parameter constrained to string (it does not matter that T is not yet specified; even { [P in "x" as Foo<P>]: undefined } would have the same problem because P is generic,) runs afoul the problem that [T] extends [infer Y] ? Y : never loses the constraint for Y. So, does this all address the question and I can write an answer? Do you want to [edit] to use your new [mre]? How should I proceed?

Of course, your answer gave me an idea on how to explain this. I have edited the example.

The issue is essentially the same as reported in microsoft/TypeScript#23132 and microsoft/TypeScript#45281. In conditional types, TypeScript doesn't really propagate constraints on the checked type to constraints on the output type.
One might expect or hope that for
type Foo<T extends string> = [T] extends [infer Y] ? Y : never

TypeScript would see that T is constrained to string and thus constrain the inferred Y to string, so that Foo<T> would be constrained to string | never which is just string. But this does not happen. There is effectively no constraint on Y, so it is implicitly constrained to unknown.
And therefore if you use Foo<T> in a place where T is generic, TypeScript treats it as potentially unknown, and thus you can get errors in places where something more specific than unknown is required:
type Test = { [T in "foo" as Foo<T>]: undefined } // error!
//                           ~~~~~~
// Type 'Foo<T>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
// Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.

Note that this doesn't happen when you write Foo<T> where T is a specific type, like Foo<"foo"> or Foo<string>. That's because TypeScript can simply evaluate those types to "foo" and string. There is no "constraint" for such types, they are known.  TypeScript has no problem with { [K in "foo"]: 0 } so it has no problem with { [K in Foo<"foo">]: 0 }; those are the same type.

So, TypeScript doesn't propagate constraints through conditional types like this. If you need such things to work, you'll have to work around it. The easiest way to work around is to use extends constraints in infer clauses. This is where you write infer Y extends string instead of infer Y:
type Foo<T extends string> = [T] extends [infer Y extends string] ? Y : never
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

type Test = { [T in "foo" as Foo<T>]: undefined } // okay now

This tells TypeScript that it should only allow the conditional type to be true if the inferred Y is a subtype of string.  This doesn't change the behavior of Foo<T> for any specific T because we already knew that Y must be a subtype of string.  So Foo<string> and Foo<"foo"> are the same as before.  But now TypeScript has a constraint of string on Y, and thus a constraint of string on Foo<T>, and therefore Test above compiles with no problem.
Playground link to code
